# Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str' error

Tags: python, string, input

Hello when I try to make a basic input panel I encounter with that error.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

```
ip = str(input(">>> "))
if ip == "0" | ip == "00":
    pass
elif ip == "1" | ip == "01":
    send()
elif ip == "2" | ip == "02":
    st()
elif ip == "3" | ip == "03":
    fst()
elif ip == "4" | ip == "04":
    res
```

Just WHY???

Comment: I think you want to use the `or` operator, not `|`.

Comment: You can take a look at [`this site`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/logical_operators_example.htm) for basic logical operators for python.

Comment: Note - input() returns a string - no conversion required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` is the bitwise-or operator. From [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), `|` binds tighter than `==`, so

```
ip == "0" | ip == "00"
```

could be expressed as

```
ip == ("0" | ip) == "00"
```

`str` doesn't support bitwise-or, so the `"0" | ip` fails. You wanted logical `or`. Since `or` has lower precedence than `==`, this works

```
ip == "0" or ip == "00"
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the bitwise or operator `|` instead of the logical operator `or`. In this case you're comparing the statement bitwise and not logical. Therefore, the correct use for your case where comparing logic in an if is not recommended unless you knowingly use the bitwise logic.